# apt-get install proxy problem: no such file or directory

Tags: apt, proxy

I can't seem to install anything using apt. I guess it's a proxy issue, but I checked `/etc/environment` and I've included all the necessary proxy information. I've included a picture of the errors I'm getting. Help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
$ sudo apt-get install install-info
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
install-info is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required: 
0ad-data 0ad-data-common fonts-texgyre libenet2a libglc0 libglewmx1.10
libgloox11 libnvtt2 libphysfs1 tex-common warzone2100-data
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 334 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/etc/environment: line 2: http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080:: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The contents of my environment variable are:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
http_proxy= "http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080:"
https_proxy= "http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080:"
ftp_proxy= "http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080:"
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
HTTP_PROXY= "http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080:"
HTTPS_PROXY="http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080:"
FTP_PROXY="http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080:"
NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

Comment: Can you please copy-paste the text instead of using a screenshot? And add the contents of `/etc/environment` as well.

Comment: I apologize. I've made the edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your variable assignments have spaces after the `=`. There should be no space. They should look like:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
http_proxy="http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080:"
https_proxy="http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080:"
ftp_proxy="http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080:"
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080:"
HTTPS_PROXY="http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080:"
FTP_PROXY="http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080:"
NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed it immediately. I had no idea it was such a small mistake.

Comment: @Aleph Happens. :) Note for the future: Linux Mint is off-topic here, questions for Mint should be asked on [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

your Proxy is incorrect: "http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080:"

Must be => "http://proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080" <-without the last colon